# Collision detection with PyGame

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame

I have been making a 2d platformer using Python with PyGame. It has all be going good, but I have stumbled accross many problems with collision detection. Here they are:

1. You can't go through objects that have the exact space for you to go through
2. You can go through the ceiling (very weird)

The code I have is very big and I think that, since it involves multiple classes, I should post it on GitHub, so here is the link to my repository: https://github.com/pta2002/SuperBros.

But just for reference, here is my colliion detection method:

```
def detectCollisions(self, x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2):

    if x2 + w2 >= x1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 >= y2:
        return 1

    elif x2 + w2 >= x1 + w1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 >= y2:
        return 2

    elif x2 + w2 >= x1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 + h1 >= y2:
        return 3

    elif x2 + w2 >= x1 + w1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 + h1 >= y2:
        return 4

    else:
        return 0
```

and here is my update method:

```
def update(self, gravity, block_list):
    if self.velocity < 0:
        self.falling = True

    collision = 0
    blockX, blockY = 0, 0
    self.canMoveRight = True
    self.canMoveLeft = True

    for block in block_list:
        collision = self.detectCollisions(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height,
         block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height)

        if not collision == 0:
            blockX = block.x
            blockY = block.y
            break

    if not collision == 0:
        if self.falling:
            self.falling = False
            self.onGround = True
            self.velocity = 0
            self.y = block.y - self.height
        else:
            if collision == 2:
                self.canMoveRight = False

            if collision == 1:
                self.canMoveLeft = False
    else:
        self.falling = True
        self.onGround = False

    if not self.onGround:
        self.velocity += gravity

    self.y -= self.velocity
    if (self.canMoveRight and self.xvel > 0) or (self.canMoveLeft and self.xvel < 0):
        self.x += self.xvel

    if self.jumping:
        if self.onGround:
            self.velocity = 8
            self.onGround = False

    if self.cur_image >= self.num_images - 1:
        self.cur_image = 0
    else:
        self.cur_image += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Pygame `Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) already comes with a few collision detection functions that may just do what you need:

- `pygame.Rect.contains`: test if one rectangle is inside another
- `pygame.Rect.collidepoint`: test if a point is inside a rectangle
- `pygame.Rect.colliderect`: test if two rectangles overlap
- `pygame.Rect.collidelist`: test if one rectangle in a list intersects
- `pygame.Rect.collidelistall`: test if all rectangles in a list
  intersect
- `pygame.Rect.collidedict`: test if one rectangle in a dictionary
  intersects
- `pygame.Rect.collidedictall`: test if all rectangles in a dictionary
  intersect

Instead of having a `detectCollisions`method that takes `x1`, `y1`, `w1`, `h1`, `x2`, `y2`, `w2` and `h2`, at the sprite initialization you could set its `Rect`, move and blit the sprite using this same `Rect` as argument, **and** check for collisions with something as simple as:

```
sprite1.rect.colliderect(sprite2.rect)
```

From a [A Newbie Guide to pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html):

> **Rects are your friends**.
>
> [...] I have to admit my favorite part of pygame is the lowly Rect class. A
>   rect is simply a rectangle – defined only by the position of its top
>   left corner, its width, and its height. Many pygame functions take
>   rects as arguments, and they also take ‘rectstyles’, a sequence that
>   has the same values as a rect. So if I need a rectangle that defines
>   the area between 10, 20 and 40, 50, I can do any of the following:
>
> ```
> rect = pygame.Rect(10, 20, 30, 30)
> rect = pygame.Rect((10, 20, 30, 30))
> rect = pygame.Rect((10, 20), (30, 30))
> rect = (10, 20, 30, 30)
> rect = ((10, 20, 30, 30))
> ```
>
> If you use any of the first three versions, however, you get access to
>   **Rect’s utility functions. These include functions to move, shrink and
>   inflate rects, find the union of two rects, and a variety of
>   collision-detection functions**.
>
> For example, suppose I’d like to get a list of all the sprites that
>   contain a point (x, y) – maybe the player clicked there, or maybe
>   that’s the current location of a bullet. It’s simple if each sprite
>   has a .rect member – I just do:
>
> ```
> sprites_clicked = [sprite for sprite in all_my_sprites_list
>                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(x, y)]
> ```
>
> Rects have no other relation to surfaces or graphics functions, other
>   than the fact that you can use them as arguments. You can also use
>   them in places that have nothing to do with graphics, but still need
>   to be defined as rectangles. Every project I discover a few new places
>   to use rects where I never thought I’d need them.

So unless you have a specific reason not to rely on Pygame `Rect` and its functions, my suggestion would be: don't reinvent the wheel, stick with it.

They might even make use of some internal c code that provides better performance then implementing a pure python approach, although I'm not sure about this specific point.